# how to return ajax suceess from user defined function

Tags: function, jquery, return-value

I am having the bellow function .
Here i want to return ajax success from user defined function . How to do this

```
alert(Ajaxcall(id_array,"del"));

function Ajaxcall(id_array,type){
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "serverpage.php",
                    cache:false,
                    data: ({id:id_array,type:type}),
                    success: function(msg){

                   return msg; //this returns nothing

                    }
            }); 

            alert(msg); // this one undefined

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "a" in "ajax" stands for "asynchronous" ("Asynchronous JavaScript And XML", although these days most people use it with JSON rather than XML).

So your `Ajaxcall` function returns before the ajax call completes, which is why you can't return the message as a return value.

The usual thing to do is to pass in a callback instead:

```
Ajaxcall(id_array,"del", functon(msg) {
    alert(msg);
});

function Ajaxcall(id_array,type, callback){
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "serverpage.php",
                    cache:false,
                    data: ({id:id_array,type:type}),
                    success: function(msg){

                        callback(msg);

                    }
            }); 
}
```

It's surprisingly easy with JavaScript, because JavaScript's functions are [closures](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) and can be defined inline. So for instance, suppose you wanted to do this:

```
function foo() {
    var ajaxStuff, localData;

    localData = doSomething();
    ajaxStuff = getAjaxStuff();
    doSomethingElse(ajaxStuff);
    doAnotherThing(localData);
}
```

you can literally rewrite that asynchronously like this:

```
function foo() {
    var localData;

    localData = doSomething();
    getAjaxStuff(function(ajaxStuff) {
        doSomethingElse(ajaxStuff);
        doAnotherThing(localData);
    });
}
```

I should note that it's *possible* to make an ajax call synchronous. In jQuery, you do that by passing the `async` option in (setting it `false`). But it's a ***very bad idea***. Synchronous ajax calls lock up the UI of most browsers in a very user-unfriendly fashion. Instead, restructure your code slightly as above.

But just for completeness:

```
alert(Ajaxcall(id_array,"del"));

function Ajaxcall(id_array,type){
    var returnValue;
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "serverpage.php",
                    cache:false,
                    async: false,        // <== Synchronous request, very bad idea
                    data: ({id:id_array,type:type}),
                    success: function(msg){

                        returnValue = msg;

                    }
            }); 
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: ca i use msg outside that callback Ajaxcall(id_array,"del",function(msg){  }); alert(msg); like this

Comment: @gowri, no, `msg` does not exist outside the callback.

Comment: @gowri: You could assign it to a variable you declared in the containing scope, but again, you have to think asynchronously -- will it be set at the time you use it? That's why I gave the example of how easy it is in JavaScript to modify step-by-step logic to handle asynchronousness. At the point of an async operation, start a new function and move everything that should follow *into* that function. You can even nest these.

Comment: thank you T.J .. not yet understand  asynchronous and synchronous stuff. but i'll learn ASAP

Comment: @gowri: No worries, glad that helped. Once you get your head around it, it's easy. [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/izobi3) that uses three separate ajax calls, each nested, and demonstrates how each of the callbacks is a closure over a local variable in the function where they're defined. (If you're not too sure about closures, read the [article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) linked in the answer.) Best,

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has a number of global Ajax event handlers, including `$.ajaxComplete()` and `$.ajaxSuccess()` (ref: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).

The code can be attached to any DOM element and looks like this:

```
/* Gets called when all request completes successfully */
      $("#myElement").ajaxSuccess(function(event,request,settings){
          $(this).html("<h4>Successful ajax request</h4>");
      });
```

This code will execute whenever any successful Ajax call is completed.